Reference request: Splitting of cotangent sequnce of $\mathbb{P}^n$
I am currently reading about the cotangent sequence $$0 \to \mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}^2 \to \Omega_{Y|X}^1 \to \Omega_X^1 \to 0$$ and need a reference to show that the sequence splits when $Y = \mathbb{P}^n$ and $X$ is a linear subvariety.

https://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/0506-216/216Cjun2807.pdf

I don't know a reference off hand, but your situation can be formulated in terms of essentially elementary linear algebra as follows: $W$ is a subspace of a vector space $V$ and $X = \mathbb{P}(W) \subset \mathbb{P}(V) = Y$. The cotangent bundle on projective space is $Q^*(-1)$, where $Q$ is the tautological quotient bundle. At a point $L \in \mathbb{P}(V)$, the fiber of $Q$ is $V/L$ and the fiber of $Q^*$ is $\{ \phi \in V^* : \phi(L) = 0\}$.
So, twisting by $O(1)$, the sequence becomes
$0 \to N_{X/Y}^*(1) \to Q_Y^*|_X \to Q_X^* \to 0$
and the right-hand map is restriction of functionals, $\{\phi \in V^* : \phi(L) = 0\} \to \{\phi \in W^* : \phi(L) = 0\}$ by $\phi \mapsto \phi|_W$.
To split this, the short answer is: pick, once and for all, a splitting of the ambient vector space as $V = W \oplus U$.
Now since we have restricted to $L \in \mathbb{P}(W)$, the fiber $V/L$ of $Q_Y|_X$ splits as $W/L \oplus U$ (since $L \subset W$), and since this is natural in $L$, we obtain $Q_Y|_X \cong Q_X \oplus U$. Here $U$ means the trivial vector bundle with fiber $U$ on $\mathbb{P}(W)$. Dualizing this isomorphism preserves the splitting, we have
$\{\phi \in V^* : \phi(L) = 0\} \cong \{\phi \in W^* : \phi(L) = 0\} \oplus U^*$
by $\phi \mapsto (\phi|_W, \phi|_U)$
which says $Q_Y^*|_X \cong Q_X^* \oplus U^*$ via restriction of functionals.
